# wordpress post_where set only for my costum post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, hooks

in my Wordpress plugin i used the post_where filter but it's effect all other post type of my site.

my question is how to set this filter only for "property" post only

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'posts_where'); 

function posts_where($where)
{
       global $wpdb,$wp_query;
       $where .= ' AND latitude.meta_key="wp_gp_latitude" ';
       $where .= ' AND longitude.meta_key="wp_gp_longitude" ';  

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Please file an [edit] and explain what do you mean you want the filter only for custom post types. How are you using the filter and what is the expected out come

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the post_Type query variable is not set for standard types (page, post and attachment, see [WP_QUery class file line 2396 on trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2396)), only for custom post types, so this is how you can test for each type,

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where', 10, 2);
function posts_where( $args, $wp_query_obj ) {
  $type = $wp_query_obj->query_vars['post_type'];
  switch(true){
    case 'any'==$type: //query any type (see codex for more details).
      break;
    case !empty($type) && is_array($type):
      //multiple post types define
      break;
    case !empty($type):
      //post type is a custom post.
      //this is where you would check for your post type,
      if ($type == 'property') {
        $args .= ' AND latitude.meta_key="wp_gp_latitude" ';
        $args .= ' AND longitude.meta_key="wp_gp_longitude" ';
      }
      break;
    case $wp_query_obj->is_attachment():
      //post type is empty but is a media.
      $type='attachemnt';
      break;
    case $wp_query_obj->is_page():
      //post type is empty but is a page.
      $type='page';
      break;
    default:
      //post type is empty and not an attachment nor a page, so is a post.
      $type='post';
      break;
  }
  return $where;
}
```

for more information on the WP_Query object and its methods, see the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) page.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where', 10, 2);

function posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    global $wpdb,$wp_query;
    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'property') {
        $where .= ' AND latitude.meta_key="wp_gp_latitude" ';
        $where .= ' AND longitude.meta_key="wp_gp_longitude" ';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

If you add `$priority = 10 //normal` and `$accepted_args = 2` to your `add_filter` function,
you will have a `$query` object in your `posts_where` function that you can put a conditional on your `post_type` for 'property' to have it only affect your custom post type.

Here is a link to the WP codex documentation for the `add_filter` function:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: Please don't just dump code, [edit] your answer and add some explanation how this bit of code will solve the issue.